# Finding the radius of convergence of the following series

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck with the following problem that says:

> Let $k$ be a fixed positive integer. Find $R_k$, the radius of convergence of
>   the power series $$\sum{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}^{n^2}z^{kn}$$ .

I was trying to apply Cauchy's root test . If I take  $a_n={\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}^{n^2}z^{kn}$,then $|a_n^{\frac1n}|\to e|z^k|$ as $n \to \infty$ and so the series will converge if $e|z^k| <1 $ that is if $|z|<\frac{1}{e^k}$. So, $R_k=\frac{1}{e^k}$.

Am I right? Can someone explain it? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You almost had it, but it is $$|z|>\frac{1}{e^{1/k}}$$ You have to take the $k$th root of $|z^k|<1/e$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks a lot sir.